# Where does an android.graphics.Path object store its data?

Tags: android

I can see nested classes in the Docs, but no fields, just methods.
I'm trying to understand how the path is built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In private data fields.  They aren't in the docs because you can't access them-  they're private.  They're also subject to change at any time so putting them in the documentation would be counterproductive, you aren't supposed ot know or use them-  if you did your application woul likely break with the next version of Android.

Comment: Thanks. That's going to help me read and understand a lot of doc in the future !